# Check is string contains special characters and at least 2 characters amongs digit and letter

Tags: javascript, regex, passwords

Hi guys I trying to check if password contains special caracters and at least 2 characters (digit or letter)
So like this:

```
("&#€$&&÷") ====> false

("&#&'&*#5") ====> false

(">~<<`<•5t") ====> true

("{\><>\tt") =====> true

("65%#^$*@") ====> true

("7373673") ====> false

("7267373~") ====> true
```

I've tried this regular expression but It seems not working:

```
/^((?=.*\d{2})|(?=.*?[a-zA-Z]{2}))/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assert the 2 occurrences of a character or digit in the same lookahead, and then match at least a single "special" character.

Using a case insensitive pattern:

```
^(?=(?:[^a-z\d\n]*[a-z\d]){2})[a-z\d]*[~!@#$%^&*()_+<>•`{}\\][~!@#$%^&*()_+<>•`{}\\a-z\d]*$
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:[^a-z\d\n]*[a-z\d]){2}` Assert 2 occurrences of either a char a-z or a digit. The `[^a-z\d\n]*` part negates the character class using `[^` to prevent unnecessary backtracking
- `[a-z\d]*` Match optional chars a-z or a digit
- `` [~!@#$%^&*()_+<>•`{}\] `` Match a special character
- `` [~!@#$%^&()_+<>•`{}\a-z\d] `` Match optional allowed chars
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/33LOoq/1)

Comment: OOOh thanks man, you saved me a lot of reseach. regex is pretty hard

Comment: Sorry for asking again but I'm beginner at it and I'm trying to achieve a project. How about string containing special characteres, digits, lower an Upper case letter?

Comment: @tanjonaRandrianasolo You can add another lookahead to the pattern, see https://regex101.com/r/KnTrzl/1

Comment: can you send me a link to learn regex please? I don't know yet what is a lookahead

Comment: @tanjonaRandrianasolo See https://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html